# React.js Reconciliation algorithm explain in plain english

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, vue.js

I was checking out the react internals, seen and tried to look into the algorithm used by react to update the dom nodes. It was interesting. I then checked and read more about it. checked how vue.js does something similar using v-dom or something similar.

I want to understand how react does it, and want a detailed comparison between react and vue's dom manipulation and update way.

Answer (score 2):

> **If you're wanting long, highly detailed, in-depth explanations then this isn't what this site is really for**

Since react is going to redesign their entire internal structure of updating react components inside the dom. They've uploaded a video regarding the changes with a deep explanation of what is going on. I highly recommend to watch this video to get an overall view on this algorithm.

(React Fiber announcement - React Conference 2017)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCuYPiUIONs

Comment: it provides overall idea how it works, I want to know the internals if you can explain that please explain, and also provide comparison with vue.

Comment: If you're wanting long, highly detailed, in-depth explanations then this isn't what this site is really for

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. if you edit the post I will up vote the answer. thanks